# Copiando as perguntas do Stack Overflow

Tags: debate, conteúdo

Pessoal algum tempo atrás foi criada a pergunta: [Melhor site de Q&A, existe? [em suspenso]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25694/melhor-site-de-qa-existe).

Acredito que na intenção de divulgar um dos sites que estavam lá, a questão é que por curiosidade acessei os outros sites, porque realmente não conhecia.

Minha surpresa foi que quando acessei um dos sites, todas as perguntas eram copias das perguntas do [stackstackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), copias idênticas somente um <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> e <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

O site também conta com um sistema de pontuação, a pessoa pega as questões com boas votações e copia para lá.

**Isso é normal? Aceitável?**

Não sei se me expressei direito, todos os dias entro no Stack Overflow, é muito útil para mim, às questões realmente são sobre dúvidas das pessoas, agora ficar usando as questões em outro site somente por pontuação?

O [site](http://nerd.com.br/questions) para quem quiser conferir.

Comment: Eu (ainda) não sei qual o procedimento quanto a isso, mas obviamente é mais um site com a brilhante ideia de usurpar conteúdo para roubar tráfego. Não é o primeiro, nem será o último. Algo que a equipe do SO pode fazer é verificar qual a origem do "robô" que lê as perguntas e bloqueá-la.

Comment: Todas as essas peguntas pelo que eu vi, são feitas pela mesma pessoa (real), até com perfil no linkedin, não sei se devo colocar o nome aqui, mais tem lá no site, não tem como checar se essa pessoa tem cadastro no SO?

Comment: Há dois "sócios" nessa empreitada. Pelo menos pelo nome real não os encontrei. Acho que apenas a equipe do SO poderia verificar isso.

Comment: Para constar, excluí a pergunta linkada por considerar que seu objetivo poderia ser atrair visitas para aquele site. Quem quiser visitar o tal site, é o http://nerd.com.br/

Comment: Sem problemas @bfavaretto, porém não tenho nenhuma ligação nem interesse em divulgar aquele ou qualquer site aqui no SO.
Acredito que o SO não é um canal para divulgação de nada e se mesmo assim aqui o fizesse, com certeza não iria divulgar um site tão pobre em conteúdo. Como mencionei o SO é uma ferramente muito importante para o meu trabalho, não arriscaria qualquer credibilidade que tenha ganho a troco de nada.

Comment: Claro @RafaelTheodoro, eu quis dizer que o autor *daquela pergunta* poderia ter a intenção de divulgar o site, não você. Como a pergunta estava fechada e é claramente *off-topic*, resolvi excluir. Desculpe se dei a entender que estava falando de você.

Comment: Sem problema @bfavaretto 
=)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do meta original do Stack Exchange:

[Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

Resposta aceita (tradução livre):

Stack Overflow é licenciado sob Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Generic, que afirma:

> Atribuição - Você deve atribuir o trabalho da forma especificada pelo autor ou licenciante (mas não de forma a sugerir que estes o apoiam ou subscrevem o seu uso da obra).

Eu acho que é bastante claro que eles não conseguiram fazer isso (ou qualquer atribuição que seja). Então na minha opinião não: esse uso não é legítimo.

Comment: Exatamente. Criar um site com mecanismo igual ou semelhante ao do SO não é o problema, mas copiar conteúdo sem atribuição sim. Existem vários sites que copiam conteúdo automaticamente para gerar tráfego. Não parece ser o caso deste, a cópia ali parece ser manual. Mas a falta de atribuição é um problema assim mesmo.

Answer (score 12):

O OnoSendai [já explicou bem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1737) o problema daquele site: ele usa conteúdo nosso sem a devida atribuição.

Existe um [procedimento oficial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) para reportar esse tipo de ocorrência para a Stack Exchange, que tomará as devidas providências legais a seu critério. **[Entre em contato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact)** com a equipe da SE, fornecendo as seguintes informações:

- a URL da cópia
- a URL do post original no nosso site (ou outro da rede)
- no caso de cópias bem posicionadas em buscas, informar o termo buscado e o mecanismo de busca usado
- qualquer outro detalhe que considere relevante

Comment: só por curiosidade: suponha que o autor de uma resposta queira postar sua própria resposta em seu blog pessoal, ainda assim ele teria que fazer a atribuição ? (digo no caso de não postar a pergunta e sim somente sua própria resposta).

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas também que isso é uma coisa que acaba sendo feita naturalmente (ou pelo menos deveria). O mesmo é válido se alguém quiser postar no site algo que já postou no blog pessoal. Geralmente quando você republica qualquer coisa que já escreveu, em qualquer meio (impresso ou eletrônico), convém citar onde aquilo já foi publicado antes.

Comment: Isso mesmo @bfavaretto.